# Selecting Randomly within an Array

Tags: python, arrays, random

Given an array `x = [2,3,5,4,1,7,4,2,8]` I am looking to create a second array `y` which is a length `p` and consists of a random election of the elements within `x`. Is there an easier way other than doing the following

```
x = [2,3,5,4,1,7,4,2,8]
random.shuffle(x)
p = 5
y = x[0:p]
print y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `random.sample`:

```
x = [2,3,5,4,1,7,4,2,8]
y = random.sample(x, p)
```